# 1D multiple lines plot with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have a dataframe with x1 and x2 columns. I want to plot each row as an unidimensional line where x1 is the start and x2 is the end. Follows I have my solution which is not very cool. Besides it is slow when plotting 900 lines in the same plot.

Create some example data:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd    
df_lines = pd.DataFrame({'x1': np.linspace(1,50,50)*2, 'x2': np.linspace(1,50,50)*2+1})
```

My solution:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def plot(dataframe):
    plt.figure()
    for item in dataframe.iterrows():
        x1 = int(item[1]['x1'])
        x2 = int(item[1]['x2'])
        plt.hlines(0,x1,x2)

plot(df_lines)
```

It actually works but I think it could be improved. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matplotlib can save a lot of time drawing lines, when they are organized in a `LineCollection`. Instead of drawing 50 individual `hlines`, like the other answers do, you create one single object.

Such a `LineCollection` requires an array of the line vertices as input, it needs to be of shape `(number of lines, points per line, 2)`. So in this case `(50,2,2)`.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd    
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection

df_lines = pd.DataFrame({'x1': np.linspace(1,50,50)*2, 
                         'x2': np.linspace(1,50,50)*2+1})

segs = np.zeros((len(df_lines), 2,2))
segs[:,:,0] = df_lines[["x1","x2"]].values


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

line_segments = LineCollection(segs)
ax.add_collection(line_segments)

ax.set_xlim(0,102)
ax.set_ylim(-1,1)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Best optimization so far, when tested with 500 hundred lines you start seeing that you gain a lot of performance with it. Nice one :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with `axis=1` for process by rows:

```
def plot(dataframe):
    plt.figure()
    dataframe.apply(lambda x: plt.hlines(0,x['x1'],x['x2']), axis=1)

plot(df_lines)
```

Answer (score 2):

I add to the nice [@jezrael response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46345272/7954504) the possibility to do this in the numpy framework using [numpy.apply_along_axis](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html). Performance-wise it is equivalent to DataFrame.apply:

```
def plot(dataframe):
    plt.figure()
    np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: plt.hlines(0,x[0],x[1]), 1,dataframe.values)
    plt.show()

plot(df_lines)
```