# Is It Possible To Set Transparency When Using LineCollection in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

There are a number of [helpful posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46345100/1d-multiple-lines-plot-with-pandas) for using LineCollections in Matplotlib.

I have working code, but am having trouble figuring out how to set the transparency of the lines. For example, in Pandas it's as easy as doing:

```
df.plot(kind='line',alpha=.25)
```

However, I chose the LineCollection method because I want to plot a dataframe with >15k lines and the above example does not work.

I've tried adding `ax.set_alpha(.25)` in my code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.set_xlim(np.min(may_days), np.max(may_days))
ax.set_ylim(np.min(may_segments.min()), np.max(may_segments.max()))

line_segments = LineCollection(may_segments,cmap='jet')

line_segments.set_array(may_days)
ax.add_collection(line_segments)

ax.set_alpha(.05)

ax.set_title('Daily May Data')

plt.show()
```

but there is no change.

Unfortunately I cannot provide a sample of the data with which I'm working; however, I've found the second example this [Matplotlib gallery doc](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/shapes_and_collections/line_collection.html) to be easy to copy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do it the same way you'd do it in pandas.

```
line_segments = LineCollection(may_segments, cmap='jet', alpha=0.05)
```